# android storing static data

Tags: android, static

I am developing an android application and I have encountered a problem about storing some static data.

The data table is static and quite large (above 200 entries) and will be re-used frequently. Those data will be fetched by filter just like SQL operation.

But I do not want to store in the SQLite simply because the information can be revealed in the rooted devices and I don't want those data be revealed.

I have tried to store in the XML but I concerned the cost when everytime loading the XML file.

What is the best way to solve this issue so that the data can be retrieved and reused with short and fixed time, at the same time the SQL operation (or similarly, normally I just dont want to proceed the first 199 rows when I just want to fetch the row 200's data).

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what solution did you end up going with?

Comment: SQLlite is applied

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SQLLite database encrypted with [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/)

Encryption should alleviate your concerns about the data being accessible on a rooted device.  SQLCipher is used in commercial applications (including the one I work on).  We have had professional, 3rd-party security audits that have blessed this as a secure method for storing sensitive data on Android.

Answer (score -1):

You can user Static Array for Storing static data
like,

public static String[] stringArray = new String[size];

OR

public static String[] stringArray = {"String1","String2","String3"};